# saving data from textboxes into textfile

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to save data from textboxes into a textfile. I got a handful of textboxes so I was wondering if there was another way to do this instead of having to name all the textboxes?

Here's a shortened version of what I have:

```
string slog = @"StockLog.txt";

StreamWriter raw_data = new StreamWriter(slog, true);
raw_data.WriteLine(
    txt_count.Text + ","
    + date_log.Text + ","
    + txt_key.Text + ","
    + txt_pn.Text + ","
    + txt_desc.Text);

raw_data.Close();
```

I was thinking of making a class for this since it'd be used by multiple pages. Trying this in both wpf and winforms. Any input would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure that would save it - however on reading it back - what if any value had a comma in? You would have to name the boxes whatever you do - how else wold you get data from them even if its a,b,c,d,e,f etc

Comment: I made sure if any of the textboxes had a comma in them, it wouldn't be accepted

Comment: Do you want to save all textboxes on your form or just the ones specified?

Comment: @Riv all of the textboxes in the form :) I kinda have a bunch of textboxes so I decided to not include everything in the sample code above

Answer (score 0):

first give a name for the main grid in each window you want to save the textbox values and use this method to help you

```
        string getValuesFromAllTextBox(Grid someGrid)
        {
          string WindowValues="";
          foreach (var item in someGrid.Children)
          {
              if (item is TextBox)
              {
                WindowValues +=((TextBox)item).Text+",";
              }
          }
          if(WindowValues !="")
          WindowValues = WindowValues.TrimEnd(',');

          return WindowValues;
        }
```

Comment: From where you know this is Grid?

Comment: Each window in WPF have a Grid

Comment: if the Textboxs are not in a grid just replace the Grid with the container item you are using

Answer (score 0):

For Winforms:

1. Make a StringBuilder object
2. Do a Foreach(var ctrl in Form.Controls)
3. If ctrl is TextBox - append the text property to stringbuilder object
4. If its a container control (i.e. GroupBox or Panel) - Repeat steps 2-4 for the ctrl.Controls (instead of Form in step 2)

Finally you will have all the textbox texts in the string builder. Use it as you wish.
You can make a separate class to reuse this code. Just pass the class/form object to the method.

Comment: What if the container has containers that has controls?

Comment: @Riv He should use recursion instead of checking type on p.4.

Comment: @Michal - True, I believed nik will be able to think through that.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider iterating through controls with recursion.

```
public string Parse(Control MainControl)
{
   string Result = "";
   foreach (var Ctrl in MainControl.Controls)
   { 
      if (Ctrl.GetType() == TypeOf(TextBox))
      {
          Result += (TextBox)Ctrl.Text + ",";
      }
      if (Ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
      {
          Result += Parse(Ctrl);
      }
   }
   return Result;
}
```

Comment: P.S. Not sure if same solution will work for WPF and WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the controls on your form, including controls within containers using recursion. You can use an extension method for it:

```
public static class ControlExtension
{
  public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControls<Control>(this IEnumerable<Control> parent,
        Func<Control, IEnumerable<Control>> childrenSelector)
   {              
        foreach (Control item in parent)
        {
          // Yield parent items
          yield return item;

          // Yield all of the children.
          foreach (Control child in childrenSelector(item).GetControls(childrenSelector))
          {                  
              yield return child;
          }
        }
   }
}
```

Then you can use the extension method to get all the controls recursively, and then filter by the type that you want:

```
var allControls = this.Controls.Cast<Control>().GetControls(x => x.Controls.Cast<Control>());
var onlyTextBoxes = allControls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

You can then use that to write your output.